# C programming; string manipulation issue

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to take string: `"TX 5 (SBS) RF On - P5"` and make it `"TX%205%20(SBS)%20RF%20On%20-%20P5"` where all the spaces are replaced with a `"%20"`

I've tried the following code on an online compiler which returns the output I need, however on VS I'm getting the output: `TX%205(SBS)RFOn-P5`. Anybody?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;

    char gen_alias[60];
    char alias[] = "TX 5 (SBS) RF On - P5";

    j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(alias); i++, j++)
    {
        if(alias[i] == '\x20')
        {
            gen_alias[j] = '%';
            j++;
            gen_alias[j] = '2';
            j++;
            gen_alias[j] = '0';
        }
        else
        {
            gen_alias[j] = alias[i];
        }
    }

    printf("%s", gen_alias);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Runs fine for me.  Did you try recompiling?  Is this the **exact** code you're using?

Comment: Executing your script results in  
TX%205%20(SBS)%20RF%20On%20-%20P5
 for me